# Rotate point A and B on a sphere to point C and D on a sphere

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I have two points on a sphere, $A$ and $B$. They are fixed on the sphere: if the sphere moves, the points will move with it. 
Now, i have two other points on the same sphere, $C$ and $D$. I need to rotate the sphere such that $A$ and $B$ will end up on $C$ and $D$.

Using the Pyton API I can turn the sphere around the using the axis-angle rotation method:

```py
axisAC = np.cross(A,C)
rotateAC = np.arccos(np.dot(A,C)/(np.linalg.norm(A)*np.linalg.norm(C)))
object.rotation_axis_angle = [angle] + list(axisAC)
```

This will rotate the sphere around the axis that is perpendicular to A and C, with the angle between A and C, thus putting point A on point C. However, trying the same with the B to D will not work, because `object.rotation_axis_angle` will reset if I feed it a new value.

So, my question is, is there a way to make the 'new' rotation zero, so I can apply the same trick again, or is there an easy way of doing the rotation of A and B to C and D in one operation?

Comment: Have a look at `v1.rotation_difference(v2)` using blenders vector API. (`v1` and `v2` are vectors)   The result is a quaternion describing the minimal axis and angle to rotate.  (`q.to_matrix()` provides a rotation matrix.   If O is sphere centre, fristly rotate sphere using rotation difference of OA to OC to match A to C, and then use OA as axis of rotation and rotate using the singed angle between 2D projection vectors OB and OD (`v1.angle_signed(v2)`) onto plane with normal OA